# Nativescript: stackView not enabling scroll

Tags: angularjs, angular2-nativescript

I am building a first nativescript app with angular 2.

I have created a simple stackView to view some item contents:

```
   <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="item-section">
      <Image [src]="item.image"  width="80%" class="item-image"></Image>
      <label>{{item.title}}</label>
      <label text="{{ item.title }}" class="item-title"></label>
      <label text="{{ item.subtitle }}" class="item-subtitle"></label>
      <label text="{{ item.date }}" class="item-date"></label>
      <label text="{{ item.description }}" textWrap="true" class="item-description"></label>
      <label text="Google maps" ></label>
  </StackLayout>
```

Sometimes the item.description is long and larger than the screen display. In this case, I am not able to scroll down to see the end of the description. How do I best enable all the content to display?

Note: I have created a list view and all the content displays fine with a scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer by wrapping the description in a scroll-view:

https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-samples/ui/scroll-view.html